# Javascript: Prototype provides interface to call object's method infinitely

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout

I am looking for a JavaScript implementation for the following requirements:

1. A prototype implements a *next* and a *run* method. If next is invoked, an iteration function *once* is called once. If run is invoked, *once* is called infinitely often (abortion via user request must also be possible, but is currently not reflected in the source code).
2. *once* takes a done argument which it will invoke once it is done.
3. The iteration function *once* is defined in the *prototype*, but can and will be overridden by the child *Child*.
4. Infinite iterations as in *run* must be possible, hence the stack must be lost (as it happens when the function is called by setTimeout.

My current problem with this source code: *once* of *Parent* is invoked, not of *Child*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function write(msg) {
        var t = document.createTextNode(msg);
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(t);
        document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(li);
      }

      var Parent = function () {
        var running = 0;

        var run = function () {
          running = Infinity;
          invokeNextIter();
        };

        var next = function () {
          running = 1;
          invokeNextIter();
        };

        var invokeNextIter = function () {
          if (running > 0) {
            running -= 1;
            setTimeout(function () { once(invokeNextIter); }, 1);
          }
        };

        var once = function (done) {
          var time = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
          write(time + " sec");
          setTimeout(done, time * 1000);
        };

        return {
          run: run,
          once: once
        };
      };

      var Child = function () {
        var once = function (done) {
          write("2 sec as always");
          setTimeout(done, 2000);
        };

        var p = new Parent();
        return Object.create(p, { once : once });
      };

      function main() {
        var c = new Child();
        c.run();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="main()">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Was not able to get this running with Function.prototype.bind or associated techniques. Any help appreciated gratefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in your case, the only function which is different between `Parent` and `Child` is your **once()** function.

So you have to start from your `Parent` class, build the core, then you will add instance method to `Parent` and `child`, to override the `once()` function.

We will use the **prototypal inheritance**. The rule is that you can prototype any object that is initialized with the `new` keyword, and that includes native javascript objects.

```
  function write(msg) {
     var t = document.createTextNode(msg);
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.appendChild(t);
     document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(li);
   }

   var Parent = function(){
     //Retrieve context
     var self = this;

     var running = 0
     //Create a `run` function which will refer to the current context
     self.run = function(){
       running = Infinity;
       invokeNextIter();
     }

     //Declare our private function
     var next = function () {
        running = 1;
        invokeNextIter();
      };

     var invokeNextIter = function () {
        if (running > 0) {
          running -= 1;
          setTimeout(function () {
            //Call once method which is in the prototype of the current context
            self.once(invokeNextIter);
          }, 1);
        }
      };
   }

   //Add a "once" instance method to Parent
   Parent.prototype.once = function(done){
     var time = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
     write(time + " sec");
     setTimeout(function(){
       done();
     }, time * 1000);
   }


   //Create our Child 'class'
   var Child = function(){

   }

   //Declare Child as a subclass of the first
   Child.prototype = new Parent();

   //Add a "once" instance method to Child and override the "once" parent method
   Child.prototype.once = function(done){
     write("1.5 sec as always");
     setTimeout(function(){
       done();
     }, 1500);
   }


   function main(){
     // Create instances and see the overridden behavior
     var c = new Child();
     var p = new Parent();
     //c.run() will call child once() method
     c.run();
     //p.run() will call parent once() method
     p.run();
   }
```

Here, you can see the `self.run()` and `self.once()`. `Self` variable will refer to the current instance.

Comment: I cannot make it run by providing all methods via the return object in the constructor (as in my example), but you are absolutely right. Your approach works and satisfies what I asked for. And an approach with prototypical inheritance is what I was obviously looking for. Thank you!